# html form error in django project

Tags: python, django, django-forms, forms

I'm rather new to programming. I followed a tutorial about building a ***django project***. I've gotten an error that looks like this while running the server and launching the site (error):

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /

Variables and attributes may not begin with underscores: 'form.as._p'

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version:     1.9
Exception Type:     TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    

Variables and attributes may not begin with underscores: 'form.as._p'

Exception Location:     /home/vagrant/Desktop/lwc2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py in parse, line 514
Python Executable:  /home/vagrant/Desktop/lwc2/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.3
Python Path:    

['/home/vagrant/Desktop/lwc2/website',
 '/home/vagrant/Desktop/lwc2/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/vagrant/Desktop/lwc2/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/home/vagrant/Desktop/lwc2/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/vagrant/Desktop/lwc2/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/vagrant/Desktop/lwc2/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/vagrant/Desktop/lwc2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/vagrant/Desktop/lwc2/lib/python2.7/site-packages']

Server time:    Thu, 10 Dec 2015 15:04:07 +0000
Error during template rendering

In template /home/vagrant/Desktop/lwc2/website/website/templates/home.html, error at line 9
Variables and attributes may not begin with underscores: 'form.as._p'
1   {% extends "base.html" %}
2   
3   
4   {% block content %}
5   
6   <h1>Hello, welcome to the home page</h1>
7   
8   <form>
9       {{form.as._p }}
10  </form>
11  
12  
13  
14  {% endblock %}
```

This is a the code that's defining my form : (inside `form.py`)

```
from django import forms

class EmailForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField()

`
```

This is the code defining my view and implementing form : (inside `views.py`)

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import EmailForm
def home(request):
    form = EmailForm
    context = {"form":form}
    template = "home.html"
    return render(request, template, context)
```

And this is the `home.html` thats extending the `base.html`:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}


{% block content %}

<h1>Hello, welcome to the home page</h1>

<form>
    {{form.as._p }}
</form>



{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo. It should be `{{ form.as_p }}`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in your template: The `{{form.as._p }}` should have been `{{ form.as_p }}`.